# Can't subclass UIColor?

Tags: objective-c, ios, subclass, uicolor

I'm trying to subclass UIColor, and I can't seem to figure out what's wrong.

In my PColor.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface PColor : UIColor {
    BOOL isAvailable;
    int colorId;
}
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL isAvailable;
@property (nonatomic, assign) int colorId;
@end
```

...and in my PColor.m

```
#import "PColor.h"

@implementation PColor
@synthesize isAvailable;
@synthesize colorId;
@end
```

Upon instantiating a PColor object, I get:

```
//warning: incompatible Objective-C types initializing 'struct UIColor *', expected 'struct PColor *'
PColor *pcolor = [[PColor alloc] initWithHue:1 saturation:0 brightness:0 alpha:1];
```

Am I missing something? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`UIColor` is a **class cluster** use [associative references](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocAssociativeReferences.html) in a category to add properties! All of the custom init methods on `UIColor` return a `UIColor*` not an `id` so you can not easily subclass `UIColor` nor should you try.

UIColor+PCOLOR.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <objc/runtime.h>

@interface UIColor(PCOLOR)
//Properties prefixed to try and avoid future conflicts
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL pIsAvailable;
@property (nonatomic, assign) int pColorId;
@end
```

UIColor+PCOLOR.h

```
#import "UIColor+PCOLOR.h"

@implementation UIColor(PCOLOR)

static char PCOLOR_ISAVAILABLE_KEY;
static char PCOLOR_COLORID_KEY;

@dynamic pIsAvailable, pColorId;

-(void)setPIsAvailable:(BOOL)pIsAvailable
{
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &PCOLOR_ISAVAILABLE_KEY, [NSNumber numberWithBool:pIsAvailable], OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
}

-(BOOL)pIsAvailable
{
    return [(NSNumber*)objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &PCOLOR_ISAVAILABLE_KEY) boolValue];
}

-(void)setPColorId:(int)pColorId
{
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &PCOLOR_COLORID_KEY, [NSNumber numberWithInt:pColorId], OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
}

-(int)pColorId
{
    return  [(NSNumber*)objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &PCOLOR_COLORID_KEY) intValue];
}

@end
```

USAGE

```
UIColor *pcolor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithHue:1 saturation:0 brightness:0 alpha:1];
pcolor.pColorId = 2352;
pcolor.pIsAvailable = YES;
NSLog(@"\nClass: %@\nColor ID: %d\nIs Availabled: %@", 
      NSStringFromClass([pcolor class]), 
      pcolor.pColorId, 
      pcolor.pIsAvailable ? @"YES" : @"NO");
[pcolor release];
```

Comment: This is a very thorough answer... thanks Joe.  Associative references = awesome.

Comment: nice answer one Up... one dout why OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC here is for Bool values OBJC_ASSOCIATION_ASSIGN is enough right...?

Comment: @jeeva if you look you can only store `objects` as  associated objects so the `BOOL` needs to be wrapped in an `NSNumber` which then needs to be retained.

Answer (score 5):

From [UIColor Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIColor_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

*Most developers should have no need to subclass UIColor. The only time doing so might be necessary is if you require support for additional colorspaces or color models.*

You should use Category.  For example:

```
@interface UIColor (PColor)
    - (BOOL) isAvailable;
    - (int) colorId;
@end
```

In the implementation file:

```
@implementation UIColor (PColor)

    - (BOOL)isAvailable {
        // do what you want to do
        // return your BOOL
    }

    - (int)colorId  {
        // do what you want to do
        // return id of color
    }

@end
```

Comment: Agreed. I think a category is more suitable and Black Frog's example will work great for what you're needing.

Comment: Many thanks for all the responses guys - great info all around.

Comment: Sorry Black Frog, but I've gotta give this one to Joe for the bit on Associative References. Thanks a million though.

Answer (score 1):

Because UIColor alloc might not do what you expect it to do: allocating an instance of UIColor. It may be kind of a factory method, which looks first what colors have already been used or belong to a standard set of colors and give it back instead of creating a new instance. In which case you will be getting UIColor instead of PColors and what means that inheriting UIColor was not a good idea.

Prefer composition over inheritance - embed UIColor within a PColor. Or use a category on UIColor (you can't have new instance variables in this case).

Answer (score 0):

The init methods of UIColor return a UIColor* rather than id as with most classes, so you would have to assign it to a UIColor rather than your subclass to avoid the warning.