# How to inherit from UIColor correctly or how to access UIColor subclass property

Tags: ios, objective-c

Here is my code:

```
@interface SubColor : UIColor

@property (atomic, assign) int key;

+ (id)colorWithkey:(int)key color:(UIColor *)color;

@end
```

---

```
@implementation SubColor

- (id)initWithCGColor:(CGColorRef)cgColor withkey:(ThemeConfigKey)key{
    if (self = [super initWithCGColor:cgColor]) {
        _key = key;
    }

    return self;
}

- (BOOL)isKindOfClass:(Class)aClass{
    NSLog(@"isKindOfClass:%@", NSStringFromClass(aClass));
    return [super isKindOfClass:aClass];
}

+ (id)colorWithkey:(int)key color:(UIColor *)color{
    SubColor *subColor = [[SubColor alloc] initWithCGColor:color.CGColor withkey:key];
    if([subColor isKindOfClass:[SubColor class]]){
        NSLog(@"123");
    }

    return subColor;
}

@end
```

NSLog don't output @"isKindOfClass:%@" and @"123". That's because the SubColor instance is just a kind of UIColor class instead of SubColor class. How can I get to know the color is my own SubColor while color is using in other place?

Otherwize, some methods discussed in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5731299/cant-subclass-uicolor) is not perfect in some reason. Because UIColor will be reused by system in some case!  A associated key with 'A' color may be replaced to a associated key with 'B' color if the two colors contain equal RGB value. this make me crazy!

Comment: Just to be clear, are you saying that the problem with using the solution in the other question is because you might need to have two colors with the same RGB value that have two different theme keys? That is a problem if `UIColor` returns the same instance in that case.

Comment: @rmaddy two colors with the same RGB value that have two different theme keys is what I need, my question is sometimes UIColor is reused by system.Through my practice with the NSLog output,  a textLabel on UITableViewCell set a textcolor with "a" key and value "0xffffff", after cell layoutsubview methods, the textLabel textcolor is replaced with a color with "b" key and value "0xffffff". By tracking， the color with "b" key and value "0xffffff" is using by navigationBar titleView which is also a UILabel.

Comment: Right, that confirms what I thought you meant. Since `UIColor` seems to return some fixed instances for some common colors, it makes what you want to do very difficult. What about creating your class so it extends `NSObject` instead of `UIColor` and has two properties - your key and the `UIColor`?

Comment: That's also very difficult, my class should also can be accessible by system UILabel textColor and other method using UIColor. Not all color is created by my methods. Inherit from UIColor is meet my request. But  now I don't konw how to judge UIColor is my subColor. that's cray!

Comment: Then you are stuck. `UIColor` doesn't properly support subclassing since it returns some fixed color instances and your needs prevent using a class that has a `UIColor` property. You need another approach for tracking which theme the color is associated with. Without knowing your needs, it's difficult to offer other suggestions.

Comment: @rmaddy : what I need is just what you say: theme color. while changing theme, I need to know the all visiable view that has theme color and change to new color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because UIColor is kind of [Class Clusters](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/ClassCluster.html). And detail description in Cocoa Fundamentals Guide for [Class Clusters](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/ClassClusters/ClassClusters.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010810-CH4).

`The class cluster architecture involves a trade-off between simplicity and extensibility: Having a few public classes stand in for a multitude of private ones makes it easier to learn and use the classes in a framework but somewhat harder to create subclasses within any of the clusters. However, if it’s rarely necessary to create a subclass, then the cluster architecture is clearly beneficial. Clusters are used in the Foundation framework in just these situations.`

How to create subclass within a Class Cluster also be mentioned in document.

Although I have solved my problem through other way. I think it's necessary list relative linker at here and close the answer.

Hope this can help others who occur similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

As rmaddy said in the comment, `UIColor` does not support subclassing. I am just guessing your needs at this point, however consider making a `UIColor` category instead. It will probably solve your problems.

I think you just want to have a set of colours in a configuration, and another set in another. Writing a `UIColor` category does that.