# Implementing Codable for UIColor

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, decodable

Is it possible to implement the `Encodable` and `Decodable` properties for `UIColor`

When I try to add a `Decodable` extension I get an error

```
extension UIColor : Decodable {
    public required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        self.init(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
    }
}
```

> error: ColorStuff.playground:98:21: error: initializer requirement 'init(from:)' can only be satisfied by a `required` initializer in the definition of non-final class 'UIColor'
>       public required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {

Am I missing something obvious here?

I have no issues with the `Encodable` extension - it seems its a `Decodable` issue.

The error message implies to me that I cannot do this due to not having access to the `UIColor` class definition

Comment: Compare https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46522572/initializer-requirement-initjson-can-only-be-satisfied-by-a-required-init.

Comment: You're missing this obvious error: ```'required' initializer must be declared directly in class 'UIColor' (not in an extension)```

Comment: Yea thats what i was afraid of - as said by last sentence.  So we'll call it a resounding NO WAY JOSE

Comment: You can always attempt to [subclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21212513/how-to-inherit-from-uicolor-correctly-or-how-to-access-uicolor-subclass-property) it and have the subclass implement `Codable`. Or perhaps write a wrapper for it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You cannot make `UIColor` conform to `Decodable` in an extension because of the error given by the compiler.

One solution is to make a `Codable` wrapper type and use that instead.

Since `UIColor` already conforms to `NSCoding`, let's just write a generic type so we can encode and decode anything that conforms to `NSCoding`.

```
import UIKit

struct WrapperOfNSCoding<Wrapped>: Codable where Wrapped: NSCoding {
    var wrapped: Wrapped

    init(_ wrapped: Wrapped) { self.wrapped = wrapped }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        let data = try container.decode(Data.self)
        guard let object = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: data) else {
            throw DecodingError.dataCorruptedError(in: container, debugDescription: "failed to unarchive an object")
        }
        guard let wrapped = object as? Wrapped else {
            throw DecodingError.typeMismatch(Wrapped.self, DecodingError.Context(codingPath: container.codingPath, debugDescription: "unarchived object type was \(type(of: object))"))
        }
        self.wrapped = wrapped
    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        let data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: wrapped)
        var container = try encoder.singleValueContainer()
        try container.encode(data)
    }
}

let colors = [UIColor.red, UIColor.brown]
print(colors)
let jsonData = try! JSONEncoder().encode(colors.map({ WrapperOfNSCoding($0) }))
let colors2 = try! JSONDecoder().decode([WrapperOfNSCoding<UIColor>].self, from: jsonData).map({ $0.wrapped })
print(colors2)
```

Comment: If I try to use your (excellent) wrapper with a single value it throws an error when encoding - ie - jsonData = try! JSONEncoder().encode([w]) succeeds let jsonData = try! JSONEncoder().encode(w) fails with let w = WrapperOfNSCoding(colors[0]) error is  Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: Swift.EncodingError.invalidValue(WrapperOfNSCoding #1... Why would that be

Comment: I will be happy to help you if you post your own top-level question. Feel free to add a comment here linking to it if you do.

Comment: Thanks very much - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49330725/wrapperofnscoding-fails-with-single-value

Answer (score 1):

There is as way to make `UIColor` `Codable` despite that required init.
You can extend `Codable` itself, so that `UIColor` starts conforming it automatically.

```
import UIKit

extension Decodable where Self: NSSecureCoding {

    public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        let data = try container.decode(Data.self)
        guard let object = try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData(data) as? Self else {
            throw DecodingError.dataCorruptedError(
                in: container,
                debugDescription: "Invalid object"
            )
        }
        self = object
    }
}

extension Encodable where Self: NSSecureCoding {
    public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
        let data = try NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: self, requiringSecureCoding: true)
        try container.encode(data)
    }
    
}

extension UIColor: Codable { }
```

Check it

```
import XCTest
class CodingTextCase: XCTestCase {
    let encoder = JSONEncoder()
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    
    func testUIColor() throws {
        let colorAsJSON = try encoder.encode(UIColor.red)
        print(String(data: colorAsJSON, encoding: .utf8)!)
        let uiColor = try? decoder.decode(UIColor.self, from: colorAsJSON)
        XCTAssertEqual(uiColor!, UIColor.red)
    }
}
CodingTextCase.defaultTestSuite.run()
```

But please note that in this case data for instance of UIColor will take about 5 hundred bytes and storing it as RGBA [can be more compact](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71927562/9480608).