# WrapperOfNSCoding fails with single value

Tags: swift, codable

A question from [Implementing Codable for UIColor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48566443/implementing-codable-for-uicolor/48567698?noredirect=1#comment85663410_48567698)

```
    struct WrapperOfNSCoding<Wrapped>: Codable where Wrapped: NSCoding {
        var wrapped: Wrapped

        init(_ wrapped: Wrapped) { self.wrapped = wrapped }

        init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
            let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
            let data = try container.decode(Data.self)
            guard let object = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: data) else {
                throw DecodingError.dataCorruptedError(in: container, debugDescription: "failed to unarchive an object")
            }
            guard let wrapped = object as? Wrapped else {
                throw DecodingError.typeMismatch(Wrapped.self, DecodingError.Context(codingPath: container.codingPath, debugDescription: "unarchived object type was \(type(of: object))"))
            }
            self.wrapped = wrapped
        }

        func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
            let data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: wrapped)
            var container = try encoder.singleValueContainer()
            try container.encode(data)
        }
    }

    let colors = [NSColor.red, NSColor.brown]
    print(colors)
    let w = WrapperOfNSCoding(colors[0])
    let jsonData = try! JSONEncoder().encode(w) - fails
    let jsonData = try! JSONEncoder().encode(colors.map({ WrapperOfNSCoding($0) })) - succeeds

    print(jsonData)
    let colors2 = try! JSONDecoder().decode([WrapperOfNSCoding<NSColor>].self, from: jsonData).map({ $0.wrapped })
    print(colors2)
```

The error is when a single value is used in the encoder

```
let w = WrapperOfNSCoding(colors[0])
let jsonData = try! JSONEncoder().encode(w)
```

error is

> Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error:
>   Swift.EncodingError.invalidValue(WrapperOfNSCoding #1...

This succeeds

```
let w = WrapperOfNSCoding([colors[0]])
let jsonData = try! JSONEncoder().encode(w)
```

Why would that be

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JSONEncoder` need valid JSON context on the top level, which could be either `[:]` (Dictionary) or `[]` (Array), inside you can place an element like in this example `string`.

When you save any `NSCoding` object, the compiler treats that object as the string. In the case of `JSONEncoder().encode(w)`, you are trying to encode an `NSCoding` object which acts as a `string` object instead of regular `JSON` object.

In the case of `JSONEncoder().encode([w])`, the object has created an array and each element has a string which is `NSCoding` in your case.

In another way `w` data is a string and `[w]` is an array with each index is having a string, therefore `JSONEncoder` is not giving you an error with `[w]` and giving you an error for `w`.