# Custom Struct: Type does not conform to protocol 'Decodable'

Tags: ios, swift, struct, codable

I would like to be able to save a `Custom-struct`  to `UserDefaults` but for that I need it to be `Codable`.. I tried it like this:

```
struct Wishlist: Codable {
    var name: String
    var image: UIImage
    var wishData: [Wish]
    var color: UIColor
    var textColor: UIColor
    var index: Int
}
```

But that gives me this `error`:

> Type 'Wishlist' does not conform to protocol 'Decodable'

Here is my `Class Wish` , maybe that's where the problem is:

```
class Wish: NSObject {
    public var wishName : String?
    public var checkedStatus : Bool?
    public var wishLink : String?
    public var wishPrice : String?
    public var wishNote : String?
    public var wishImage : UIImage?
    
    init(withWishName name: String, link: String, price: String, note: String, image: UIImage, checked: Bool) {
        super.init()
        wishName = name
        checkedStatus = checked
        wishLink = link
        wishPrice = price
        wishNote = note
        wishImage = image
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here??

Comment: instead of 'Struct Wishlist: Codable'. make it Struct Wishlist: Decodable. If that does not solve the issue, make your Class Wish: Codable, or Decodable, not NSObject

Comment: Also your class Wish have to implement Codable protocol

Comment: If I add `Codable`  to `Wish` I get the same error in `Wish` as in `Wishlist`

Comment: doesn't solve the issue. If I make `Wish` Codable I get this error: `Type 'Wish' does not conform to protocol 'Decodable'`  and `'super' members cannot be referenced in a root class`

Comment: Both `UIImage` and `UIColor` don't conform to `Codable`. Map `UIImage` to `Data` and `UIColor` to a hex string value or an array of `Double`. And **never** declare properties as optional which are initialized with non-optional values.

Comment: @vadian thanks for the answer, could you maybe elaborate on that? How would that look like in my `struct` and `class` ? And I will change the `optinal` !

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53619084/parse-uicolor-from-json-file-with-codable-swift) is an example for `UIColor` and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46197785/how-to-conform-uiimage-to-codable) one for `UIImage`

Comment: Out of curiosity, why is `Wish` a `class` and why is `Wishlist` a `struct`? And even if you wanted to make `Wish` a `class`, why subclass `NSObject`?

Comment: @Rob tbh there is no reason. I might as well just make both `structs`. I dont really know when to use what exactly but they both work just fine so I didnt really bother. What would you suggest me to do ?

Comment: @vadian and assuming I did that, what would I have to add then ? Just `Codable` to `Wishlist`  ?

Comment: Every type which is going to be encoded/decoded must conform to Codable

Comment: @vadian alright, makes sense

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You will need to make `Wish` adopt `Codable`.

But because `UIImage` and `UIColor` are not `Codable`, you’ll have to manually implement them as outlined in [Encoding and Decoding Custom Types](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types):

```
struct Wishlist: Codable {
    var name: String
    var image: UIImage
    var wishes: [Wish]
    var color: UIColor
    var textColor: UIColor
    var index: Int

    init(name: String, image: UIImage, wishes: [Wish], color: UIColor, textColor: UIColor, index: Int) {
        self.name = name
        self.image = image
        self.wishes = wishes
        self.color = color
        self.textColor = textColor
        self.index = index
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

        name = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
        wishes = try values.decode([Wish].self, forKey: .wishData)
        color = try values.decode(Color.self, forKey: .color).uiColor
        textColor = try values.decode(Color.self, forKey: .textColor).uiColor
        index = try values.decode(Int.self, forKey: .index)

        let data = try values.decode(Data.self, forKey: .image)
        guard let image = UIImage(data: data) else {
            throw DecodingError.dataCorruptedError(forKey: .image, in: values, debugDescription: "Invalid image data")
        }
        self.image = image
    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

        try container.encode(name, forKey: .name)
        try container.encode(wishes, forKey: .wishData)
        try container.encode(Color(uiColor: color), forKey: .color)
        try container.encode(Color(uiColor: textColor), forKey: .textColor)
        try container.encode(index, forKey: .index)
        try container.encode(image.pngData(), forKey: .image)
    }

}

struct Wish: Codable {
    public var name: String
    public var checkedStatus: Bool
    public var link: String
    public var price: String
    public var note: String
    public var image: UIImage

    init(name: String, link: String, price: String, note: String, image: UIImage, checkedStatus: Bool) {
        self.name = name
        self.checkedStatus = checkedStatus
        self.link = link
        self.price = price
        self.note = note
        self.image = image
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

        name = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
        checkedStatus = try values.decode(Bool.self, forKey: .checkedStatus)
        link = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .link)
        price = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .price)
        note = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .note)

        let data = try values.decode(Data.self, forKey: .image)
        guard let image = UIImage(data: data) else {
            throw DecodingError.dataCorruptedError(forKey: .image, in: values, debugDescription: "Invalid image data")
        }
        self.image = image
    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

        try container.encode(name, forKey: .name)
        try container.encode(checkedStatus, forKey: .checkedStatus)
        try container.encode(link, forKey: .link)
        try container.encode(price, forKey: .price)
        try container.encode(note, forKey: .note)
        try container.encode(image.pngData(), forKey: .image)
    }
}
```

Where I’d use this as a convenient way to encode `UIColor` objects:

```
struct Color: Codable {
    let red: CGFloat
    let green: CGFloat
    let blue: CGFloat
    let alpha: CGFloat

    init(red: CGFloat, green: CGFloat, blue: CGFloat, alpha: CGFloat) {
        self.red = red
        self.green = green
        self.blue = blue
        self.alpha = alpha
    }

    init(uiColor: UIColor) {
        var red: CGFloat = 0
        var green: CGFloat = 0
        var blue: CGFloat = 0
        var alpha: CGFloat = 0

        uiColor.getRed(&red, green: &green, blue: &blue, alpha: &alpha)

        self.red = red
        self.green = green
        self.blue = blue
        self.alpha = alpha
    }

    var uiColor: UIColor { UIColor(red: red, green: green, blue: blue, alpha: alpha) }
}
```

Note, I did a couple of unrelated changes:

- I made both of these `struct`. I wouldn’t introduce reference types (much less `NSObject` subclasses) unless necessary.
- I simplified some of the property names. E.g. in `Wish`, we wouldn’t generally use `wish` prefix in property names. I also wouldn’t use “data” in a property name unless it was, in fact, a `Data`.
- I updated `init` methods to use standard naming conventions.

---

By the way, another approach is to avoid using UIKit types within model types at all. This eliminates the need for custom encoders/decoders at all. And you can have platform-specific extensions, that provide the necessary convenience initializers that bridge to the UIKit types. E.g.:

```swift
// MARK: - Wishlist

struct Wishlist: Codable {
    let name: String
    let imageData: Data     // rather than `UIImage`
    let wishes: [Wish]
    let color: Color        // rather than `UIColor`
    let textColor: Color    // rather than `UIColor`
    let index: Int
}

// MARK: Wishlist UIKit extension

#if os(iOS)
extension Wishlist {
    init(name: String, image: UIImage, wishes: [Wish], color: UIColor, textColor: UIColor, index: Int) {
        self.init(
            name: name,
            imageData: image.pngData()!,
            wishes: wishes,
            color: Color(uiColor: color),
            textColor: Color(uiColor: textColor),
            index: index
        )
    }

    var image: UIImage? { UIImage(data: imageData) }
}
#endif

// MARK: - Wish

struct Wish: Codable {
    let name: String
    let checkedStatus: Bool
    let link: URL           // rather than `String`
    let price: String
    let note: String
    let imageData: Data     // rather than `UIImage`
}

// MARK: Wish UIKit extension

#if os(iOS)
extension Wish {
    init(name: String, link: URL, price: String, note: String, image: UIImage, checkedStatus: Bool) {
        self.init(
            name: name,
            checkedStatus: checkedStatus,
            link: link,
            price: price,
            note: note,
            imageData: image.pngData()!
        )
    }

    var image: UIImage? { UIImage(data: imageData) }
}
#endif
```

Note, I not only eliminated `UIColor` from the model types, but also `UIImage`, too. Now, above I shifted the `UIImage` to `Data`, but really, the image payload probably does not belong in this model type at all. You should just have image URLs or asset identifiers, and decouple the image fetch and storage from the model altogether. (Because images and model objects tend to have very different memory characteristics, you often want images fetched as they are needed and stored within some flushable cache. But that is beyond the scope of this question.)

Comment: this is a 10/10 answer. Thanks you! Great explanation as well, really appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 1):

in your case, you should add `CodingKeys` enum and not using `UIColor` nor `UIImage` data type. I got the same error before, but then I realized that the CodingKey doesn't match with the struct nor there is `non-codable` Data type. just change the data type to your custom codable object.

wrong example:

```
public struct DtClip: Codable {

    // MARK: Properties
    public var video: String?
    public var preview: String?
    public var clip: String?
    public var trailer: Any?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case video = "video"
        case preview = "preview"
        case clip = "clip"
    }
}
```

from the example we know that `trailer` isn't in the `codingKeys` yet. You should add all the props to the `CodingKeys`. And `Any` data type should be changed to codable data type like `String`, `Int`, or `Trailer` (custom  codable data type). below is the correct example:

```
public struct DtClip: Codable {

    // MARK: Properties
    public var video: String?
    public var preview: String?
    public var clip: String?
    public var trailer: Trailer?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case video = "video"
        case preview = "preview"
        case clip = "clip"
        case trailer = "trailer"
    }
}

public struct Trailer: Codable {

    // MARK: Properties
    public var name: String?
    public var id: Int?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
       case name, url
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`UIImage` does not conform to `Codable`. You could convert it to Base64 first and then store *that* in `UserDefaults`.

Comment: Or, just get the `Data` (which you’d need to base64 encode, anyway) and store that directly and bypass the manual base64 encoding.

Comment: @Rob there are several suggestions here but u seem to have quite a good understanding of what I have to do here. Could you maybe elaborate ? :)