# Implementing swift equatable protocol gives me bad access error. why?

Tags: ios, swift, compiler-errors, protocols

here is my code.  it seems that when i subclass UIColor to make it equatable i get a memory error.  why is that?

```
class MyColor: UIColor, Equatable {
    var name: String


    init(name: String, r: CGFloat, g: CGFloat, b: CGFloat, a: CGFloat = 1.0) {
        self.name = name
        super.init(red: r, green: g, blue: b, alpha: a)
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

}

func == (lhs: MyColor, rhs: MyColor) -> Bool {
    return lhs.name == rhs.name
}

let test1 = MyColor(name: "coolRed", r: 10, g: 12, b: 22)

let test2 = MyColor(name: "coolBlue", r: 10, g: 12, b: 22)


if test1 == test2 {
    println("hey")
}
```

[image]

Comment: Probably unrelated to your error, but your code isn't any different from `MyColor(name: "coolRed", r:1, g:1, b:1)` and `MyColor(name: "coolBlue", r:1, g:1, b:1)`

Comment: i know the actual colors arent any different, but thats unrelated to the error.. it's not perfect code at this point.  I've attached a screenshot of the error

Comment: For anyone that's interested, simply copying & pasting the code in this question to the sandbox generates the same error.

Comment: Probably unrelated to your issue (which is why this is a comment, not an answer), but the [UIColor reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIColor_Class/index.html) seems to warn against subclassing UIColor. See also [this stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5731299/cant-subclass-uicolor).

Comment: @zpasternack i think this is actually the issue..  I'm not having this problem using other classes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UIColor** is a class cluster, subclassing should be avoided.

You could use the Objective-C runtime to get the functionality you desire.

This snippet is "playground-ready".

```
import UIKit

let _nameKey = malloc(4)

extension UIColor : Equatable {

var name : String {
    get {
        return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, _nameKey) as! String
    }
    set {
         objc_setAssociatedObject(self,
            _nameKey,
            newValue,
            UInt(OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC)
        );
    }
}
}


public func ==(lhs: UIColor, rhs: UIColor) -> Bool {
    return lhs.name == rhs.name
}

let aRed = UIColor(red: 1.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: 0.0)
aRed.name = "Red"
aRed.name

let anotherRed = UIColor(red: 1.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: 0.0)
anotherRed.name = "Red"

aRed == anotherRed
```